# How to fix region missing on aws amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am currently using vue2 js with aws amplify I followed the amplify cli instruction but after testing the storage i got an error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Region is missing
at resolveRegionConfig (RegionConfig.ts?69ec:34:1)
at new S3Client (S3Client.ts?6464:654:1)
at createS3Client (S3ClientUtils.ts?2e7b:156:1)
at AWSS3ProviderManagedUpload._createNewS3Client (AWSS3ProviderManagedUpload.ts?8398:321:1)
at new AWSS3ProviderManagedUpload (AWSS3ProviderManagedUpload.ts?8398:73:1)
at AWSS3Provider.put (AWSS3Provider.ts?1d18:563:1)
at Storage.put (Storage.ts?d867:343:1)
at _callee$ (adminLayout.vue?2208:168:1)
at tryCatch (regeneratorRuntime.js?525a:86:1)
at Generator.eval [as _invoke] (regeneratorRuntime.js?525a:66:1)
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "basementlore",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/api": "^4.0.42",
    "@aws-amplify/pubsub": "^4.4.3",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.23",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "janu-vuetify-form-generator": "^0.0.24",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.6",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^6.7.96",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "sass": "~1.32",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

I also have tried to check the path C:\Users\MY PC.aws\config
but it has a region on the config file.

and on my main.js

```
import { Storage, Amplify,Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
// Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    identityPoolId: 'my_pool_key', //REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
    region: 'ap-southeast-1', // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
  },
  Storage: {
      AWSS3: {
          bucket: 'my_bucket_name', //REQUIRED -  Amazon S3 bucket name
          region: 'ap-southeast-1'
      }
  }
});
Auth.configure()
```

I dont where I have done soemthing wrong because i just followed this https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/start/install/#pre-requisites-for-installation

Comment: Please how did you resolve this

Comment: To be honest i really dont know i actually started  a new project and follow the docs and somehow it works